# How to append variables to a list and not its contents

Tags: python, list, append

I want to be able to append a variable without "unpacking it". I have a master list of movies as variables, and each variable is a list that has its characteristics. For example. `Harry_Potter = ['Harry_Potter', type[1], genre[2], genre[3], genre[4], genre[5], rating[0], origin[1]]`

Then I run a loop for example that checks if Harry_Potter has type[0], which it does. But then when I want to append the variable to a new list and not what it is assigned to.

```
Master_List = [Harry_Potter, Black_Mirror, Avenger, Cinderella,
               Snow_White, Rapunzel, Anne_with_an_E, Invented, Invented2]

New_List = []

for media in Master_List:
    if type[1] in media:
        print(type[1], 'is in', media[0])
        New_List.append(media)

print(New_List)
```

The New_List won't contain the variable name, instead it contains `['Harry_Potter', type[1], genre[2], genre[3], genre[4], genre[5], rating[0], origin[1]]` as an entry for example.

Edit: Here is the list of characteristics:

```
type = ['TV', 'MOVIE']
genre = ['ACTION', 'COMEDY', 'DRAMA', 'FANTASY',
         'FICTION', 'MYSTERY', 'ROMANCE', 'DOCUMENTARIES']
rating = ['G', 'PG', 'PG13', 'NC17', 'R']
origin = ['CANADIAN', 'FOREIGN']
```

Comment: What is `type`? This is also the name of a builtin function, so I'd avoid shadowing here if you can

Comment: It refers to another list, I will edit and put it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable have no existence by themselves, they are just references to objects. You cannot add a variable to a list, but you add the object referenced by the variable.

If you want names to matter, you should use dictionaries, and append the keys to a list.

Comment: So besides using dictionaries, I have no way around this?